# Anti-symmetric property of embedding in topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

$(X,\mathcal T)$ and $(Y,\mathcal S)$ are topological spaces. $X$ can be embedded homeomorphically in $Y$ and $Y$ can be imbedded homeomorphically in $X$.

Are $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic?

---

How about uniform spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general. The Cantor set minus any one point and the Cantor set itself are a counterexample, as are $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ and many others.